# How to Round Decimal Number in PHP

Tags: php

What I want to achieve is like this :

```
10678.62 then round to 10679 <br/>
10678.67 then round to 10679 <br/>
10678.46 then round to 10678.5 <br/>
10678.43 then 10678.43
```

what php function I can used to get it work like above example? because as far as I tried (round, ceil, etc) it must be set how much number behind comma.

**logic**

```
if .x1 x2 x3 xn (x1 is first number behind comma and so on)
if x1 >= 5 then round to integer (ex: 10678.62 then result 10679)
if x1 < 5 and x2 >=5 then x1 + 1 (ex: 10678.46 then result 10678.5)
if x1 < 5 and xz < 5 then nothing rounded 9 (ex 10678.43 then 10678.43)
```

so basicly we must see if `x1 >= 5` then rounded integer but if `x1 < 5` check next number if `x2 >= 5` then round to 1 number behind comma if not then round to two number behind comma

Any solution will be very appreciated.
regards

Comment: you can use round() or number_format($var,decimalpoints) etc look up the php manual for them

Comment: I can't work out if there's a pattern to the way those numbers are rounded...

Comment: `number_format` is right way to go here, put that as an answer.

Comment: So what's the actual logic of what you're trying to implement? Whay is .46 rounded up to .5, but .43 isn't rounded at all? You're unlikely to get the answer you want unless you can describe the logic to us

Comment: as i told before, i already tried round() but it must be set number behind comma.. example round(10678.62) then result is 10679 but when round(10678.46) result is 10678. what i want is 10678.5

Comment: Follow the OTHER suggestion. Use number_format. Btw, you can allways multiply by 10^digits, round and divide by same again.

Comment: Why exactly does 10678.43 give 10678.43? Shouldn't it be 10678.5 (round up to the half)?

Comment: logic already added to the post (edited)

Comment: the silliest rounding I've ever seen.

Comment: Given that it's a purely personal rounding method that has no corollary in mathsematics, statistics, actuarial maths or similar, you won't find a built-in function that will do this for you; but at least you've added the logic to your question now rather than leaving us all trying to guess

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what is the application of this strange rounding function?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to say how many digits it needs to round:

```
$number = 10678.48;
$pos = strpos($number, '.');
$len = strlen($number);
$digits = substr($number, $pos+1, $len-$pos);
if($digits<50){
    echo round($number,1);
}else{
    echo round($number,0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, this should work for you:

```
function formatRound($number) {
    $decimal = (string) fmod($number, 1);

    if ($decimal[2] >= 5) {
        return round($number);
    }

    if ($decimal[2] < 5 && $decimal[3] >= 5) {
        return round($number, 1);
    }

    if ($decimal[2] < 5 && $decimal[3] < 5) {
        return $number;
    }
}

var_dump(formatRound(10678.62));
var_dump(formatRound(10678.67));
var_dump(formatRound(10678.46));
var_dump(formatRound(10678.43));
```